# Trying to open a PHP application locally

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I'm trying to open a CakePHP application locally that had a composer.phar file but did not have composer.json file.

I created a default composer.json file, went into the app & console folders and tried to use `bin/cake server` to open the application but it shows `bash: bin/cake: no such file or directory`.

I am pretty sure there is one file that I need to open that will open the whole program, is there a certain file I should be looking for?  Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 1):

Without a `composer.json` file you cannot run `composer.phar install` to install all the dependencies.

So you have to proceed with a "try and fail" approach.

First of all, create the [default `composer.json` file required to run a standard installation of CakePHP](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer) and install with `composer.phar install`.

Then check the [App class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html) and look for third party packages: add them to the `composer.json` file and update.

Then start using the application and read the exceptions: there you will find info about other required dependencies. Add them to the `composer.json` file and then update.

This may take some time to be done but in the end you will have again a working application.

Except if private packages are required: in this case you will have hard times.

Hope this can help you! In bocca al lupo!

Comment: I have a file called 'build.xml', is that the exceptions you might be talking about?

Comment: From this last question it seems to me you are not so compfortable with PHP. I Think may be hard for you to install the app make it work... Anyway, exceptions are errors that raise when something in the app goes wrong. These exceptions contain useful information about the missing packages...

Comment: I was not able to find any dependencies and creating a default composer.json file did not help.  is there a way to open the program without using composer or a composer.json file?